# How to Prevent Android From Killing My Activity. Services Maybe?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, timer

I'm pretty new to Android development. I have an app that records how long the user is at work and shows them how much they've earned. It works perfectly, until Android kills the activity. Is there a way to prevent this? I've read a little about service, but I'm unsure if they are what I need or even how to use them. Any help would be awesome. Thank you for your time.
(edit) This is my clockIn() method. It's called when the user presses the clock in button.

```
public void clockIn(){
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mTimer = new Timer();
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {


        @Override
        public void run() {
            now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            seconds = date.getSeconds();   
            elapsedTime = now - start;
            earnings = (wageHour/60/60/1000)*elapsedTime;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    timeDisplay.setText("$" + String.format("%.4f", earnings));


               }
           });

             }
        }, 0, 100);
}
```

Comment: yes, just use a Service !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you tracking time? The easiest way to keep track of time is to save timestamps in a database table. e.g. checkin/checkout times. There should be no problem with killed activities.

Comment: Well the app updates how much the user is earning in real time, so I've been using a Timer() class. Each frame shows how much time has progressed and the current earnings of the user.

Comment: ok, but you can still do it with timestamps. Just update the gui each second with the difference of the checkin time and now. - A service would also work, but keep in mind, that each background operation consumes battery. Even if the display is off or the activity is not loaded. I dont know how much that would be for a Timer...

Comment: mTimer = new Timer();
mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()) I've been using this to call my updates. Do you have a better method in mind?

Comment: The method is ok. But i would suggest not to count the time in the timertask, but query the database for the begin timestamp and update the gui. This would also work fine if the activity is closed and reopened since the difference between the timestamp in the database and now is independent of the timer. - However a service would work, but it's not necessary and in my opinion to complicated for the use case.

Comment: I may be doing something similar already. I edited my question with my method. Could you take a look at it? Every 100th of a second, it shows the user how much they've earned.

Comment: That looks ok, but like you said when your method start again everything is reseted.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [foreground notifications](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/07/30/notifications-foreground-services-android-4p3.html) for a Service.